# (error code: 10011): Unknown Role in discord.py version 1.7.3

Tags: python, discord.py

im not very new in discord.py but i dont know the rewrite version well and heroku forces me to use it.
Im trying to add a role if someone reacts with the on_raw_reaction_add event. My bot has all scopes expect from the webhook and guilds.join
Somehow whenever someone reacts this error comes:  `discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role`

here is the code:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload: discord.RawReactionActionEvent):
    channel = await client.fetch_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    if message.id == 876059709889720331:
        if payload.emoji.name == u'\U0001F52B':
            guild = await client.fetch_guild(payload.guild_id)
            if guild is not None:
                member = (payload.user_id)
                print(member)
                member = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_members(), id=member)
                role1 = get(guild.roles, name="R6S")
                print(role1)
                await member.add_roles(role1)
```

i noticed that when i print (role1) it even says "R6S" but i dont know if this is important

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies here

```py
member = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_members(), id=member)
```

This will check *every* `discord.Member` instance of *every* guild your bot can see, including ones in other guilds, to find one which has the requested id. That's why you can't add this role to the user - you got the `discord.Member` instance of *another* guild in which that role doesn't exist. Remember that `utils.get` returns the **first match** it finds ([docs](http://i%20noticed%20that%20when%20i%20print%20(role1)%20it%20even%20says%20%22R6S%22%20but%20i%20dont%20know%20if%20this%20is%20important)) in case there are multiple, and as your only specification was the `id` this will have multiple matches.

If you want a user's instance from a specific guild, you can use [`Guild.get_member()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_member#discord.Guild.get_member), assuming you already have the guild (which you do as you get it a few lines higher up).

```py
member = guild.get_member(member_id_goes_here)
```